# c++ visual studio 2008 issue with two projects in one solution

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, project, solution

I have a solution created using visual studio 2008 named, "**Solution**", and i have two projects in that solution, project "**A**" and project "**B**". when i do a thing like below it shows fatal errors in the bottom. I have given in project A->properties->Additional include Directries as ../B

**project B**

**B.h**

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
class B
{
public:
    B();
    ~B();
};
```

**B.cpp**

```
#include "B.h"

B::B()
{

}

B::~B()
{

}
```

**project A**

**A.h**

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
class A
{
public:
    A();
    ~A();
};
```

**A.cpp**

```
#include "A.h"
#include "B.h"
A::A()
{
    B b;
}

A::~A()
{

}
```

**Main.cpp in project A**

```
#include "B.h"

int main()
{
    B b;
    system("pause");
}
```

when i run it says

Error   3   fatal error LNK1120: 2 unresolved externals H:\Sol\Debug\A.exe

Error   2   error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall B::B(void)" (??0B@@QAE@XZ)    A.obj

Error   1   error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall B::~B(void)" (??1B@@QAE@XZ)   A.obj

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't look like you are exporting class B out of project B.  So project A sees the declaration of class B but can't find its implementation.  What does project B build?

Comment: Does project B link?  Does it produce a dll?  Does it produce a .lib that project A is supposed to link with?  If all it produces is some .obj files, then why - what is the purpose of project B?

Comment: Thanks! i had not included obj files

Comment: If you are manually adding obj files to the link command for project A, you may as well not even have project B (just include the source files directly in project A).  Alternatively, make project B produce a static lib that project A links against.